# Sticky navigation bar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a sticky navigation bar for my web page and am having troubles with what I found. Maybe someone can help me out?

> The idea of ‘sticky position’ is to make elements on a website stick and remain visible. Those elements will initially be in their position, and then in the event of scrolling down the webpage, their position will be following the scroll.

[Here's a link to what I have which also shows the navigation bar.](http://redsky.incredifull.com)

And [here's a link to the tutorial I tried to follow](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/)

Here's some relevant CSS:

```
/* Navigation bar */
#navi {
height: 40px;
width: 961px;
background: #1e416f;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

Here's some relevant HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
 <div id="navi">
 <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">CAUL/CBUA</a></h1>

<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Committees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="tools-nav">
    <li class="login"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="email icon"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li class="twitter icon"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="search icon"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm not going to bother posting what I **did** have because there's not much in the tutorial **at all**. The **only** thing that I changed from what you see on that tutorial is where ever it says *nav* I changed it to *navi* because that's what I have in my CSS.

**OR** if anyone has any other similar ideas, I'm open to it.

Comment: [Something similar here.](http://heera.it/jquery-sticky-menu-plugin#.UhzwORtmiSo)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) is incredibly useful.

You can have a navigation bar stick once it reaches the top of the page.

```
$('#navi').waypoint('sticky');
```

and in your CSS

```
#navi .stuck { position:fixed; }
```

should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution, toggle between classes, CSS is used from your site with little additions, here's a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/AVUH4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="navi" class="default">

  <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">CAUL/CBUA</a></h1>

  <ul id="primary-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Committees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="tools-nav">
    <li class="login"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="email icon"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li class="twitter icon"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="search icon"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navi {
  height: 40px;
  width: 961px;
  background: #1e416f;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#navi a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #1e416f;
}
#navi .logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
#navi .logo a {
  float: left;
  width: 56px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
#navi .logo a:hover {
  background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) center no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
}
#primary-nav, #tools-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#primary-nav li, #primary-nav a, #tools-nav li, #tools-nav a {
  float: left;
}
#primary-nav a, #tools-nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#tools-nav a:hover {
  color: #1e416f;
}
#primary-nav li:first-child a, #tools-nav li:first-child a {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
#tools-nav {
  float: right;
}
#tools-nav .icon a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
#tools-nav .email a {
  background: url(/imgs/navi/mail.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  width: 20px;
}
#tools-nav .email a:hover {
    background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_mail.png) no-repeat scroll center center         transparent;
    width: 20px;
}
#tools-nav .twitter a {
    background: url(/imgs/navi/twitter.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    width: 20px;
}
#tools-nav .twitter a:hover {
    background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover-twitter.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    width: 20px;
}
#tools-nav .search a {
  background: url(/imgs/navi/search.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  width: 20px;
}
#tools-nav .search a:hover {
  background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_search.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  width: 20px;
}
.default {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  var navi     = $( '#navi' ),
      naviOff  = navi.offset();

  $( window ).scroll(function() {

    if($( this ).scrollTop() >= naviOff.top + navi.height() && navi.hasClass( 'default' )) {

      navi.removeClass( 'default' ).addClass( 'fixed' ).fadeIn( 'fast' );
    } 
    else if($( this ).scrollTop() <= naviOff.top && navi.hasClass( 'fixed' )) {

      navi.removeClass( 'fixed' ).addClass( 'default' ).fadeIn( 'fast' );
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: If you going to use this, use this code, because on jsFiddle I added wrapper div and some properties to html and body in order to achieve the effect.

Comment: BTW you should set CSS overflow-x: hidden; property for your site body, you have a horizontal scrollbar ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add something like the following:

```
#navi {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```